# How to share session on subdomains?

Tags: php, session

I have tried putting following line in my root HTACCESS:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .domain.com
```

But it is giving me 500 Internal server error!
How can I fix this? Or how can I share session to subdomains?

Here is the error_log message:

```
public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://xxxxx.xx/xxxxx.php
```

One more question: If two subdomains are on two different IPs, will the session still work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you read error log?

Comment: Error log message:

    public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `.htaccess` to define `php.ini` directives. Instead, add `session.cookie_domain=.domain.com` to your `php.ini` file.

If that doesn't work, you can use [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://php.net/session-set-cookie-params) before calling `session_start()`

Comment: Why not set it in .htaccess ?